# Concurrent and scalable data structure in Java to handle tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, scalability

for my current development I have many threads (`Producers`) that create `Tasks` and many threads that that consume these `Tasks` (`consumers`)

Each `Producers` is identified by a unique name; A `Tasks` is made of:

- the name of its `Producers`
- a name
- data

My question concerns the data structure used by the (`Producers`) and the (`consumers`).

#### Concurrent Queue?

Naively, we could imagine that `Producers` populate a concurrent-queue with `Tasks` and (`consumers`) reads/consumes the `Tasks` stored in the concurrent-queue.

I think that this solution would rather well scale but one single case is problematic: If a `Producers` creates very quickly two `Tasks` having the same name but not the same data (Both tasks T1 and T2 have the same name but T1 has data D1 and T2 has data D2), it is theoretically possible that they are consumed in the order T2 then T1!

#### Task Map + Queue?

Now, I imagine creating my own data structure (let's say `MyQueue`) based on Map + Queue. Such as a queue, it would have a `pop()` and a `push()` method.

- The `pop()` method would be quite simple
- The `push()` method would:

  - Check if an existing `Task` is not yet inserted in `MyQueue` (doing `find()` in the Map)

    - *if found*: data stored in the `Task` to-be-inserted would be merged with data stored in the found `Task`
    - *if not found*: the `Task` would be inserted in the Map and an entry would be added in the Queue

Of course, I'll have to make it safe for concurrent access... and that will certainly be my problem; I am almost sure that this solution won't scale.

#### So What?

So my question is now what are the best data structure I have to use in order to fulfill my requirements

Comment: You might want to look into [Reactive Java programming](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+reactive+programming&t=iphone&ia=web).

Comment: *"it is theoretically possible that they are consumed in the order "T2" then "T1"!"* No, it is more accurate to says that it's highly likely that they are consumed in **parallel** (aka **concurrently**) by different consumers, and will be processed in parallel. In concurrent programming, order is a very fluid concept.

Comment: Since elements are unique you could also try sets such as ConcurrentSkipListSet which will enforce uniqueness. You can also avoid the synchronization entirely and write different threads and merge them at the end. This could keep the things clean.

Comment: The question is a bit misleading, as it implies that it's about concurrent multi-producer-consumer, but it seems to be about running unique tasks in sequence. Before you worry about scaling, you should clarify what your requirements are.

Comment: I don't see the issue, or the need for a specific data structure? Have the producers post their tasks to a `BlockingQueue` a dispatcher listens to which will distribute it to the consumers.

Comment: daniu: `BlockingQueue` can really be a problem (unfortunately) if a `Producer` `"P1"` adds a first task `"T"` with data D1 and quickly a second task `"T"` with data D2.

In this case, the first task can be handled by a thread and the second task by another thread; If the threads handling the first task is interrupted, the thread handling the second one can complete first

Comment: So you're not actually looking to use multiple consumers. Maybe not even multiple producers. This question has nothing to do with scalability. you've got a different design problem.

Comment: Kayaman: Yes, I have multiple producers and multiple consumers; As the throughput of the producers increases, I will have to increase the number of Consumers. This is typically a question of scalability: if the data structure I use to exchange my data is blocking, my design won't scale well

Comment: Hemang Rindani: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know the `ConcurrentSkipListSet`. I am currently studying it but for the moment I cannot see how it could help me

Comment: If you want two tasks to be dependent on each other as you describe, you need to bundle them for execution; otherwise you'll never be able to reliably achieve what you're trying to do in a multithreaded environment - that's what @Kayaman means with "different design problem". Maybe look into `ForkJoinPool`. Also note that "increase the number of Consumers" will usually decrease throughput, not increase it (except you run them on a different machine).

Comment: Consumption and processing of T2 before T1 is a good think if you want to have parallelism. If you have an internal order you want to persist, you could add this order in addition to your fields (e.g. id = 1,2,3,..) and when done processing insert the result into a concurrent TreeSet, something like the ConcurrentSkipListSet proposed earlier.

Comment: You may find Heinz Kabutz's [Striped Executor Service](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue206.html) a possible candidate. It looks like it would maintain order in the way you are looking for.

Comment: Would wouldn't this work? `Map<String,Queue<Task>>` + insertion condition

Answer (score 1):

You could try Heinz Kabutz's [Striped Executor Service](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue206.html) a possible candidate.

> This magical thread pool would ensure that **all Runnables with the same stripeClass would be executed in the order they were submitted**, but StripedRunners with different stripedClasses could still execute independently.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a data structure safe for concurrent access, why not opting out **concurrent** and go for **parallel**?

Functional programming models such as [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) are a very scalable way to solve this kind of problems.

I understand that `D1` and `D2` can be either analyzed together or in isolation and the only constraint is that they shouldn't be analyzed in the wrong order. (Making some assumption here ) But in case the real problem is only the way the results are combined, there might be an easy solution.

You could remove the constraint all together allowing them to be analyzed separately and then having a reduce function that is able to re-combine them together in a sensible way.

In this case you'd have the first step as `map` and the second as `reduce`.

Even if the computation is more efficient if done in a single go, a big part of scaling, especially scaling out is accomplished by [denormalization](http://highscalability.com/scaling-secret-2-denormalizing-your-way-speed-and-profit).

Answer (score 0):

If consumers are running in parallel, I doubt there is a way to make them execute tasks with the same name sequentially. 
In your example (from comments):

> BlockingQueue can really be a problem (unfortunately) if a Producer
>   "P1" adds a first task "T" with data D1 and **quickly** a second task "T"
>   with data D2. In this case, the first task can be handled by a thread
>   and the second task by another thread; If the threads handling the
>   first task is interrupted, the thread handling the second one can
>   complete first

There is no difference if P1 submits D2 **not so quickly**. Consumer1 could still be too slow, so consumer 2 would be able to finish first. Here is an example for such scenario:

1. P1: submit D1
2. C1: read D1
3. P2: submit D2
4. C2: read D2
5. C2: process D2
6. C1: process D1

To solve it, you will have to introduce some kind of completion detection, which I believe will overcomplicate things.

---

If you have enough load and can process some tasks with different names not sequentially, then you can use a queue per consumer and put same named tasks to the same queue.

```
public class ParallelQueue {

    private final BlockingQueue<Task>[] queues;
    private final int consumersCount;

    public ParallelQueue(int consumersCount) {
        this.consumersCount = consumersCount;

        queues = new BlockingQueue[consumersCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < consumersCount; i++) {
            queues[i] = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        }
    }

    public void push(Task<?> task) {
        int index = task.name.hashCode() % consumersCount;
        queues[index].add(task);
    }

    public Task<?> pop(int consumerId) throws InterruptedException {
        int index = consumerId % consumersCount;
        return queues[index].take();
    }

    private final static class Task<T> {
        private final String name;
        private final T data;

        private Task(String name, T data) {
            this.name = name;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```